# Why was this grammar & formatting edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edits

About: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1962857

Recently, I've been suggesting a lot of edits - to make the site better. Scrolling through the list of my suggestions, I saw that this was rejected: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1962857 - mostly with the

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

reason.

However, if you look at the edit, it *is* substantial. It clarifies the question, and provides grammar and formatting fixes.

Any help?

Comment: Sometimes people rush too quickly through the suggested edits page. That one's kind of an edge case, though - it looks, at first glance, like it's invalid, even though it's not. Unfortunately, you won't usually get much more than a first glance in review.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Can I get a mod to accept it? It gave me an edit ban :)

Comment: @Undo: An edit cannot be accepted once it's been rejected, but a moderator can lift your edit ban if they see there is reason to do so.

Comment: @Undo You do have many rejected edits over the past couple days. I suggest looking through those, and looking at the reasons.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I am - kind of embarrassing - I'm 1600 rep and on my way to 2K. I hope to be a mod myself someday, and try to do everything in that light. Guess I kind of messed up.

Comment: Ah, don't worry. People won't mind if you make an effort to learn. I've had some pretty terrible questions myself.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi So it won't disqualify me for moderatorship? :)

Comment: You say here that your edit clarifies the question, but that's not mentioned at all in the edit summary (I'm also not sure if that statement is true since I'm not familiar with the topic). You also say that it provides grammar and formatting fixes, but that's pretty arguable. You've made a few wording changes (one of which was "I am" to "I'm"), and surrounded class names in backticks, neither of which really improve the question (in my opinion).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely because of the unneeded inline code blocks. Those do not *always* make things easier to read. When used excessively for things that are easily identifiable as code, such as UITableView, they actually make the post *harder* to read. Reserve its use for segments of code that belong together or for keywords that would otherwise not make sense in the context of the post without being identified as inline code.

I, personally, would have skipped this one because I don't have any strong feelings one way or the other. Just a note: changing "I am" to "I'm" is really not edit-worthy. I don't know why you even made that change.

Comment: I would reject this one but adding custom "invalid use of backticks" comment. Those need to be used for inline CODE, not any key word.

Answer (score 5):

I would have either skipped it (see below) or rejected it for the same reason.

The question was understandable before the edit. The "in-app purchases" part was the potentially redeeming part–and the reason I might have skipped it, since I don't know if that's a useful, correct, or valuable change. Nothing's wrong from the correctness standpoint.

Once edits don't have to be reviewed making edits like this doesn't strike me as being bad. The goal is to get new-ish editors to make *significant* changes that make a *Big Difference* in question quality.

There's a a wide range of what people consider "Big Enough", though.

(I *do* tend to code-format classnames as a general rule.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I reject this edit on my bad day, maybe accepting it on my good day.

I accept the edit if it makes an obvious improvement : code formatting, repair broken url.

When it comes to grammar, spelling, the edit must cover the full post. From what I think, you have just correct the grammar. There is still room for improvement on at least two things:

- Split the big block of text into paragraph. The text as it stands is not readeable.
- Correct the indentation of the block code. Too much thing here.

In fact, from my point of view, you have transform an unreadeable big block of text into another unreadeable big block of text.

As a rule of thumb, if there is more room for improvement when an edit is correcting grammar, I reject as too minor.